# What does "by (2) for each $x$ this sum is finite in some open set containing $x$" mean? ("Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-functions

> 3-11 Theorem.
> Let $A\subset \Bbb R^n$ and let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open cover of $A$. Then there is a collection $\Phi$ of $C^\infty$ functions $\varphi$ defined in an open set containing $A$, with the following properties:
>
> (1). For each $x \in A$ we have $0 \leq \varphi(x) \leq 1$.
>
> (2). For each $x \in A$ there is an open set $V$ containing $x$ such that all but finitely many $\varphi \in \Phi$ are $0$ on $V$.
>
> (3). For each $x \in A$ we have $\sum_{\varphi \in \Phi}\varphi(x)=1$ (**by (2) for each $x$ this sum is finite in some open set containing $x$**).
>
> (4). For each $\varphi \in \Phi$ there is an open set $U$ in $\mathcal{O}$ such that $\varphi = 0$ outside of some closed set contained in $U$.
>
> (A collection $\Phi$ satisfying (1) to (3) is called a $C^\infty$ partiion of unity for $A$. If $\Phi$ also satisfies (4), it is said to be subordinate to the cover $\mathcal{O}$. In this chapter we will only use continuity of the functions $\varphi$.)

The author wrote "**by (2) for each $x$ their sum is finite in some open set containing $x$**".

What does "**by (2) for each $x$ this sum is finite in some open set containing $x$**" mean?

---

(a) Does this mean $\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi} \varphi(y)<\infty$ for any $y$ in some open set containing $x$ for each $x$?
But by (3), for each $x \in A$ we have $\sum_{\varphi \in \Phi}\varphi(x)=1<\infty$.
So, I don't think this means $\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi} \varphi(y)<\infty$ for any $y$ in some open set containing $x$ for each $x$.

---

(b) Does this mean $\#\{\varphi\in\Phi:\varphi(y)\neq 0\}<\infty$ for any $y$ in some open set containing $x$ for each $x$?
But by (2), for each $x \in A$ there is an open set $V$ containing $x$ such that all but finitely many $\varphi \in \Phi$ are $0$ on $V$.
So, for any $x\in A$, $\#\{\varphi\in\Phi:\varphi(x)\neq 0\}<\infty$.
So, I don't think this means $\#\{\varphi\in\Phi:\varphi(y)\neq 0\}<\infty$ for any $y$ in some open set containing $x$ for each $x$.

---

Please explain what "**by (2) for each $x$ this sum is finite in some open set containing $x$**" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spivak actually means **(a)**, $\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi} \varphi(y)<\infty$ for any $y$ in some open set $V_x$ containing $x$, since by (2) there is an open set $V_x$ containing $x$ such that all but finitely many $\varphi \in \Phi$ vanish (this is **(b)**), and those which don't vanish are bounded. Actually, (3) is a corollary of (2) because we can normalize each $\varphi \in \Phi$ by redefining $\varphi'(x) =\varphi(x)/\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi} \varphi(x)$ for each $\varphi \in \Phi$.

Comment: By (1) and (2), we can only say $\sum_{\varphi\in\Phi}\varphi(x)<\infty$. By (3), this finite value must be always $1$. I was confused. @Ricky thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: By (3), the author imposed an additional constraint on $\varphi$.